# Dynamic relativelayout inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am adding dynamic content via Java to a relativelayout which sits inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_draw_route"
    android:id="@+id/layout_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_route"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

For some reason, the content inside the scrollview is not scrollable.

I am adding the content like this:

```
Button mButton = new Button(this);

mButton.setText(String.valueOf(singleStep.getId()));
mButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
mButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(singleStep.getId()));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.bottomMargin = 10;
lp.topMargin = 10;
lp.leftMargin = 10;
lp.rightMargin = 10;
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

// Add to relativeLayout
mRouteLayout.addView(mButton, lp);
```

I already tried calling mScrollLayout.invalidate(); after adding content, but it does not help. What I noticed is that if I do not set **android:fillViewport="true"** in the scrollview, its height is very low and only shows a part of the relative layout.

If I set the height of the relativeLayout to for example 2000dp, the container is scrollable, but only shows a small part of the actual content of the relativeLayout.

Edit: Might be important: The contents are added from the bottom to the top, each with an attribute like

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, button2.getId(););
```

Comment: Is it possible to use RecyclerView?

Comment: In my opinion, this would be very ineffective, because I would like to show a route (like a map) with connected lines between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, if you are adding your views programmatically, you have to call the requestLayout() method to refresh the view for the wrap_content to work

just do:

```
mRouteLayout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately calling this after adding the content did not help.